# Adding a number to a List with an already existing duplicate number

Tags: android

```
/*
ADDING NUMBERS TO ArrayLIST AND IF NEW NUMBER ENTERED SAME AS already EXISTING NUMBER
RESAULT IS DUBLICATE;
 */
private String[] phoneNumbers;

public String addPhoneNumber(String newPhoneNumber) throws SMSDataModelFullException {
    String result;

    if (numPhoneNumbers == phoneNumbers.length) {
        result = FULL;
    } else {
        boolean exists;
        exists = findPhoneNumberIndex(newPhoneNumber) != -1;
        if (exists) {
            result = DUPLICATE;
        } else {
            phoneNumbers[numPhoneNumbers] = newPhoneNumber;
            numPhoneNumbers++;
            result = newPhoneNumber;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This one is working perfectly to Array. I need some help with Duplicate in existing number only to List

```
private List<String> phoneNumber;

public String addPhoneNumber(String newPhoneNumber) throws SMSDataModelFullException {

    String result;

    if (maxNumPhoneNumbers!=0 && phoneNumber.size() >= maxNumPhoneNumbers) {
        throw new SMSDataModelFullException(newPhoneNumber);
    }
    else{
        boolean exist;
        exist =findPhoneNumberIndex(newPhoneNumber)!= -1;
        if(exist)
        {
            result = DUPLICATE;
        }
        else{
            phoneNumber.add(newPhoneNumber);
        }
        return  newPhoneNumber;
    }
}
```

This one is not working, what I'm doing wrong? The Duplicate in List not showing some reason.

Comment: your question is not clear. Can you clarify it a bit more ?

Comment: Post `findPhoneNumberIndex()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return `newPhoneNumber` always

```
    return  newPhoneNumber;
```

Do the same as in the first case

```
...
    if (exists) {
        result = DUPLICATE;
    } else {
        phoneNumber.add(newPhoneNumber);
        result = newPhoneNumber;
    }
}
return result;
```

Also your `findPhoneNumberIndex()` can be replaced with `phoneNumber.contains(newPhoneNumber)`

Comment: how can I change   if (numPhoneNumbers == phoneNumbers.length) to LIST?maybe instead of .length I can use size or contain?

Answer (score 1):

```
public String addPhoneNumber(String newPhoneNumber) {

    String result = newPhoneNumber;

    if(!phoneNumber.contains(newPhoneNumber)){  // if it is not already in the list
       phoneNumber.add(newPhoneNumber);         // add it to the list
    }else{
       result = "DUPLICATE";                      // if number was already in the list result = DUPLICATE
    }

    return result;

}
```

Comment: Happy to have helped. Would you be kind enough to upvote and accept the answer since it has helped you?

Comment: :) There must be a little grey 'tick' (check sign) left of my answer and below the answer's score. You click it and it becomes green! :)